# Restricting a user to select some specific folder

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am using the following code snippet to launch a folder dialog.

```
BROWSEINFO   bi; 
ZeroMemory(&bi,   sizeof(bi)); 
TCHAR   szDisplayName[MAX_PATH]; 
szDisplayName[0]    =   'a';  

bi.hwndOwner        =   NULL; 
bi.pidlRoot         =   NULL; 
bi.pszDisplayName   =   szDisplayName; 
bi.lpszTitle        =   _T("Please select a folder to locate your PGA :"); 
bi.ulFlags          =   BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;
bi.lParam           =   NULL; 
bi.iImage           =   0;  

LPITEMIDLIST   pidl   =   SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
TCHAR   szPathName[MAX_PATH]; 
if   (NULL   !=   pidl)
{
     BOOL bRet = SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl,szPathName);
     if(FALSE == bRet)
     {
          return;
     }
     else
     {
       PGA_PATH.Clear();
       PGA_PATH.SetWindowTextA(szPathName);//To set the user selected path to the text box
       SetValudata(szPathName);//to save the user selected path to the file.

     }
}
```

Now I want to restrict the user to restrict if user tries to select some specific folder (PGA).

For Example.
If user selected path=

```
                  C:\Users\mm232\Desktop\PGA 

                  C:\Users\mm232\Pictures\PGA

                  C:\Users\mm232\\PGA\Pictures
```

then do not allow the user to select the path or disable the selection.

Comment: Why not: 1) Check the selected folder name, 2) display a message box, 3) redisplay browse dialog?

Comment: @Roger Rowland I want to disable the selection . If user want to select such type of path do not let the user select.

Comment: This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx) explains what to do. Look at the "Custom Filtering" section. This is even better than your proposaé, because you can exclude unwanted folders from the list, so the users aren't even aware they exist.

Comment: Dude, you're from India. You **are** using complex scripts. How did you ever come to the conclusion, that **not** using Unicode is a Good Thing? Stop being helpless.

Answer (score 1):

The folder browser dialog is slow because it may spin up CD drives and power up sleeping external hard drives. A good design would allow the user to type the path into a textbox, and then add a browsing button next to it. The validation is then done on the textbbox not in the folder browsing dialog.

That said you do have options to prevent users from selecting certain folder by passing a callback function in the lpfn member of the BROWSEINFO structure. The callback function can do the following:

Handle BFFM_IUNKNOWN and QI lparam for IFolderFilterSite. Call IFolderFilterSite::SetFilter with your own implementation of IFolderFilter that determines each folder's visibility.

Handle BFFM_SELCHANGED, check the pidl passed in lparam and send BFFM_ENABLEOK to enable/disable the OK button. Optionally, send BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXT to show the reason why a folder can not be selected.